# .prop("checked") selects only first element

Tags: jquery

```
$(function() {
    $('.checkbox').change(function () {
    if ($('.checkbox').prop("checked")) {
        alert('checked');
        if ($('#print').length == 0) {
            $('#post').append('<input type="button" id="print" value="Print">');
        }
    } else {
        alert('unchecked');
        if ($('#print').length != 0) {
            $('#print').remove();
        }
    }
    });
});
```

With the example above, when I check the first checkbox it fires up `alert('checked');` when I uncheck, it fires up `alert('unchecked');`. Works as intended.

However, with any other element than first (second, third... checkboxes etc.) if I check the checkbox it always returns `False` from `$('.checkbox').prop("checked")`.

How can I make it to monitor all checkboxes?

Comment: Is that missing single quote in `$('.checkbox)` just a typo or is that in the code?

Comment: Just a type when adapted the code for stackoverflow community. Fixed. Thanks for spotting that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$('.checkbox')` isn't going to give you the state of the checkbox because class selectors do not return a single element.

Use: `$('.checkbox').eq(0).prop("checked")` for get the first one, or use `.each()` to access the resulting list in a loop.

```
$('.checkbox').each(function() {
    if($(this).prop("checked")) {
         alert("checked!");
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This will select all all elements with the class *checkbox* on the page:

```
if ($('.checkbox').prop("checked")) {
```

However this will select the element from which the event is fired:

```
if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
```